# PL/SQL Developer default file open

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Before when i open sql files by `PL/SQL Developer`, it opens default in Command window. Now it's opening in sql window. There was setting to open default in Command window in `PL/SQL Develeper` v11. I'm using v12. Who knows, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Add extensions to command files]

Add extensions to command files